# Count enumerated values?

Tags: mysql, count, enums

If my table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `daily_individual_tracking` (
  `daily_individual_tracking_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `daily_individual_tracking_date` date NOT NULL default ''0000-00-00'',
  `sales` enum(''no'',''yes'') NOT NULL COMMENT ''no'',
  `repairs` enum(''no'',''yes'') NOT NULL COMMENT ''no'',
  `shipping` enum(''no'',''yes'') NOT NULL COMMENT ''no'',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`daily_individual_tracking_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

basically the fields can be either yes or no.

How can I count how many yes's their are for each column over a date range?

Thanks!!

Comment: enum columns are nasty when you have a large dataset and need to add a new enum type. Depending on the schema it can take up to 45 minutes to update a table with new enum type, you may want to consider a linking (pivot) table. In your specific example, you may also want to consider a boolean column type, as it is int based vs text based and will be much faster.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can either run three queries like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM daily_individual_tracking
WHERE sales = 'YES'
AND daily_individual_tracking_date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-03-31'
```

Or if you want you can get all three at once like this:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM daily_individual_tracking
    WHERE sales = 'YES'
    AND daily_individual_tracking_date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-03-31'
) AS sales_count, (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM daily_individual_tracking
    WHERE repairs = 'YES'
    AND daily_individual_tracking_date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-03-31'
) AS repairs_count, (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM daily_individual_tracking
    WHERE shipping = 'YES'
    AND daily_individual_tracking_date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-03-31'
) AS shipping_count
```

Another way to do it is to use SUM instead of COUNT. You could try this too to see how it affects the performance:

```
SELECT
    SUM(sales = 'YES') AS sales_count,
    SUM(repairs = 'YES') AS repairs_count,
    SUM(shipping = 'YES') AS shipping_count
FROM daily_individual_tracking
WHERE daily_individual_tracking_date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-03-31'
```

Comment: I see, so do I need a to run a different query for each: sales, repairs, shipping? Thanks!!

Comment: @John: You can do it in one query if you want. I've given you a couple more options you could try.

Comment: Thanks :) I will accept your answer, but it says I have to wait 3 more minutes (a new SO feature I guess)