# Can I count how many indexes of enum type in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing, enums

[e.g. "Food" column is enum type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phqYH.png)

Can I count how many indexes of column "food"?

I've used
 `SELECT COUNT(food) FROM table WHERE code=1`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Google "mysql count of enum values" -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595763/count-enumerated-values, http://www.justskins.com/forums/how-can-i-count-167460.html

Comment: That's not the same question

Answer (score 0):

First your db schema is not good, having that said here is a solution to do it :

You can count the number of comma in food and add 1 :

```
SELECT LENGTH(food) - LENGTH(REPLACE(food, ',', '')) + 1
FROM table WHERE code=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT food)
    FROM table
```

That will give the number of *used* values for `food`.  If you have some unused values, then you need something like this:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name,
       LENGTH(column_type) - LENGTH(REPLACE(column_type, ',', '')) + 1 AS items,
       column_type
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = 'pics'
      AND data_type = 'enum';

+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| table_name  | column_name | items | column_type                                              |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| collections | index_cat   |     7 | enum('unk','wpc','family','trip','hike','music','other') |
| pics        | skip        |     2 | enum('','skip')                                          |
| pics        | prec        |     5 | enum('unk','click','est','manual','adj')                 |
| picsav      | prec        |     4 | enum('unk','click','est','manual')                       |
| picsav2     | prec        |     4 | enum('unk','click','est','manual')                       |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

(That's overkill for the specific question you asked.)